# Linking errors when building against Boost Unit Test Framework

Tags: boost, boost-unit-test-framework

I am trying to use Boost Unit Test Framework by building a stand alone library as detailed here:

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_35_0/libs/test/doc/components/utf/compilation.html

So I created a VC library project containing the mentioned files and build it and it was successful. Then I created a test project and referenced the library project I just created, but when I tried to build it, I got the following linking errors:

```
1>Type.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_impl(class boost::test_tools::predicate_result const &,class boost::unit_test::lazy_ostream const &,class boost::unit_test::basic_cstring<char const >,unsigned __int64,enum boost::test_tools::tt_detail::tool_level,enum boost::test_tools::tt_detail::check_type,unsigned __int64,...)" (?check_impl@tt_detail@test_tools@boost@@YA_NAEBVpredicate_result@23@AEBVlazy_ostream@unit_test@3@V?$basic_cstring@$$CBD@63@_KW4tool_level@123@W4check_type@123@3ZZ) referenced in function "public: void __cdecl test1::test_method(void)" (?test_method@test1@@QEAAXXZ)
1>BoostUnitTestFramework.lib(framework.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::debug::break_memory_alloc(long)" (?break_memory_alloc@debug@boost@@YAXJ@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::unit_test::framework::init(class boost::unit_test::test_suite * (__cdecl*)(int,char * * const),int,char * * const)" (?init@framework@unit_test@boost@@YAXP6APEAVtest_suite@23@HQEAPEAD@ZH0@Z)
1>BoostUnitTestFramework.lib(framework.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl boost::debug::detect_memory_leaks(bool)" (?detect_memory_leaks@debug@boost@@YAX_N@Z) referenced in function "void __cdecl boost::unit_test::framework::init(class boost::unit_test::test_suite * (__cdecl*)(int,char * * const),int,char * * const)" (?init@framework@unit_test@boost@@YAXP6APEAVtest_suite@23@HQEAPEAD@ZH0@Z)
1>BoostUnitTestFramework.lib(execution_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl boost::debug::attach_debugger(bool)" (?attach_debugger@debug@boost@@YA_N_N@Z) referenced in function "public: int __cdecl boost::detail::system_signal_exception::operator()(unsigned int,struct _EXCEPTION_POINTERS *)" (??Rsystem_signal_exception@detail@boost@@QEAAHIPEAU_EXCEPTION_POINTERS@@@Z)
1>BoostUnitTestFramework.lib(execution_monitor.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl boost::debug::under_debugger(void)" (?under_debugger@debug@boost@@YA_NXZ) referenced in function "public: int __cdecl boost::execution_monitor::execute(class boost::unit_test::callback0<int> const &)" (?execute@execution_monitor@boost@@QEAAHAEBV?$callback0@H@unit_test@2@@Z)
1>BoostUnitTestFramework.lib(unit_test_main.obj) : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class boost::unit_test::test_suite * __cdecl init_unit_test_suite(int,char * * const)" (?init_unit_test_suite@@YAPEAVtest_suite@unit_test@boost@@HQEAPEAD@Z) referenced in function main
1>C:\Users\Rafid\Workspace\MyPhysics\Builds\VC10\Tests\Debug\Tests.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
```

They seem to be mainly caused by Boost debug library, but I can't see a reason why I should get linking errors putting in mind that Boost debug library only need to be included as header files, rather than linking against as a library!

Any ideas?!

Answer (score 2):

OK, I figured out what the problem is. Apparently, the list of files mentioned in Boost's website misses the following files:

```
debug.cpp
test_main.cpp
test_tools.cpp
```

Once I added those files to my project, the test project compiled and run successfully!

UPDATE: Just wanted to mention that I actually built against Boost 1.51, so it could be that the documentation is a bit old, because I can see that in the page, they are linking the files to Boost 1.35!

Answer (score 0):

For compile unit-tests of boots 1.57 on windows,
I use [@Rafid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/196697/rafid) answer,
For me it was add this files to projects:

```
test_tools.cpp
unit_test_main.cpp
framework.cpp
```

That locate in `BOOST_DIR/libs/test/src`